# Difference between Trunc(number) and round(number)

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain how do the select statements work. And pls explain the difference between these two ??

```
select TRUNC(56.38,-1) "Truncate" FROM DUAL;

Truncate 
--------
      50


SELECT ROUND(56.38,-1) "Truncate" FROM DUAL;

Truncate
--------
      60
```

Comment: Did you look up the documentation at all?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simple.

1. The ROUND() is used to round a numeric field to the nearest number of decimals specified.

   e.g. 56 is nearer to 60 than 50 hence it will return 60.
   e.g. If instead of 56 you use 54 then 54 is nearer to 50 and it will return 50.
2. TRUNC()  returns a number truncated to a certain number of decimal places. So it always  takes the lesser value.
   e.g. If you take the number less than 56 it is 60 so it returns 50.
   e.g. Even if you use 54 it will return 50 only.